# Edit CRUD template

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, symfony

When I want to show the page who contains the list, I find another show, not like my template.

How can I Do it? You can find the code below of the view and the entity :

```
{% extends "MyAppProjetBundle::layout.html.twig" %}


{% block content %}


    <table class="record_properties">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th>Id</th>
                <td>{{ entity.id }}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Titre</th>
                <td>{{ entity.titre }}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Type</th>
                <td>{{ entity.type }}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Categorie</th>
                <td>{{ entity.categorie }}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Ville</th>
                <td>{{ entity.ville }}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Prix</th>
                <td>{{ entity.prix }}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Surface</th>
                <td>{{ entity.surface }}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Description</th>
                <td>{{ entity.description }}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Validation</th>
                <td>{{ entity.validation }}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Dateinsertion</th>
                <td>{{ entity.dateInsertion|date('Y-m-d H:i:s') }}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Iduser</th>
                <td>{{ entity.idUser }}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Idgerant</th>
                <td>{{ entity.idGerant }}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

        <ul class="record_actions">
    <li>
        <a href="{{ path('offre') }}">
            Back to the list
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="{{ path('offre_edit', { 'id': entity.id }) }}">
            Edit
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>{{ form(delete_form) }}</li>
</ul>
{% endblock %}
```

The entity :

```
<?php

namespace MyApp\ProjetBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

use MyApp\ProjetBundle\Entity\Offre;
use MyApp\ProjetBundle\Form\OffreType;

/**
 * Offre controller.
 *
 */
class OffreController extends Controller
{

    /**
     * Lists all Offre entities.
     *
     */
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $entities = $em->getRepository('MyAppProjetBundle:Offre')->findAll();

        return $this->render('MyAppProjetBundle:Offre:index.html.twig', array(
            'entities' => $entities,
        ));
    }
    /**
     * Creates a new Offre entity.
     *
     */
    public function createAction(Request $request)
    {
        $entity = new Offre();
        $form = $this->createCreateForm($entity);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($entity);
            $em->flush();

            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('offre_show', array('id' => $entity->getId())));
        }

        return $this->render('MyAppProjetBundle:Offre:new.html.twig', array(
            'entity' => $entity,
            'form'   => $form->createView(),
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Creates a form to create a Offre entity.
     *
     * @param Offre $entity The entity
     *
     * @return \Symfony\Component\Form\Form The form
     */
    private function createCreateForm(Offre $entity)
    {
        $form = $this->createForm(new OffreType(), $entity, array(
            'action' => $this->generateUrl('offre_create'),
            'method' => 'POST',
        ));

        $form->add('submit', 'submit', array('label' => 'Create'));

        return $form;
    }

    /**
     * Displays a form to create a new Offre entity.
     *
     */
    public function newAction()
    {
        $entity = new Offre();
        $form   = $this->createCreateForm($entity);

        return $this->render('MyAppProjetBundle:Offre:new.html.twig', array(
            'entity' => $entity,
            'form'   => $form->createView(),
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Finds and displays a Offre entity.
     *
     */
    public function showAction($id)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $entity = $em->getRepository('MyAppProjetBundle:Offre')->find($id);

        if (!$entity) {
            throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Offre entity.');
        }

        $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($id);

        return $this->render('MyAppProjetBundle:Offre:show.html.twig', array(
            'entity'      => $entity,
            'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Displays a form to edit an existing Offre entity.
     *
     */
    public function editAction($id)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $entity = $em->getRepository('MyAppProjetBundle:Offre')->find($id);

        if (!$entity) {
            throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Offre entity.');
        }

        $editForm = $this->createEditForm($entity);
        $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($id);

        return $this->render('MyAppProjetBundle:Offre:edit.html.twig', array(
            'entity'      => $entity,
            'edit_form'   => $editForm->createView(),
            'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
        ));
    }

    /**
    * Creates a form to edit a Offre entity.
    *
    * @param Offre $entity The entity
    *
    * @return \Symfony\Component\Form\Form The form
    */
    private function createEditForm(Offre $entity)
    {
        $form = $this->createForm(new OffreType(), $entity, array(
            'action' => $this->generateUrl('offre_update', array('id' => $entity->getId())),
            'method' => 'PUT',
        ));

        $form->add('submit', 'submit', array('label' => 'Update'));

        return $form;
    }
    /**
     * Edits an existing Offre entity.
     *
     */
    public function updateAction(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $entity = $em->getRepository('MyAppProjetBundle:Offre')->find($id);

        if (!$entity) {
            throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Offre entity.');
        }

        $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($id);
        $editForm = $this->createEditForm($entity);
        $editForm->handleRequest($request);

        if ($editForm->isValid()) {
            $em->flush();

            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('offre_edit', array('id' => $id)));
        }

        return $this->render('MyAppProjetBundle:Offre:edit.html.twig', array(
            'entity'      => $entity,
            'edit_form'   => $editForm->createView(),
            'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
        ));
    }
    /**
     * Deletes a Offre entity.
     *
     */
    public function deleteAction(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $form = $this->createDeleteForm($id);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $entity = $em->getRepository('MyAppProjetBundle:Offre')->find($id);

            if (!$entity) {
                throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Offre entity.');
            }

            $em->remove($entity);
            $em->flush();
        }

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('offre'));
    }

    /**
     * Creates a form to delete a Offre entity by id.
     *
     * @param mixed $id The entity id
     *
     * @return \Symfony\Component\Form\Form The form
     */
    private function createDeleteForm($id)
    {
        return $this->createFormBuilder()
            ->setAction($this->generateUrl('offre_delete', array('id' => $id)))
            ->setMethod('DELETE')
            ->add('submit', 'submit', array('label' => 'Delete'))
            ->getForm()
        ;
    }
}
```

Result : https://i.stack.imgur.com/xbqt9.jpg

Comment: Do u have cache enabled in twig? If so be sure to set autoreload to true as well

Comment: No, I haven't any problem with cache

Answer (score 0):

You can override the CRUD templates with the following:

From the [Symfony docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioGeneratorBundle/index.html):

> You can define custom skeleton templates by creating the same
>   directory and file structure in
>   APP_PATH/Resources/SensioGeneratorBundle/skeleton or
>   BUNDLE_PATH/Resources/SensioGeneratorBundle/skeleton if you want to
>   extend the generator bundle (to be able to share your templates for
>   instance in several projects).
>
> For instance, if you want to override the edit template for the CRUD
>   generator, create a crud/views/edit.html.twig.twig file under
>   APP_PATH/Resources/SensioGeneratorBundle/skeleton.